# JSF commandButton not calling action

Tags: jsf, action, jsf-2.2, commandbutton

I'm new at JSF and I startet with the tutorial from luv2code. Here is the link to the video: [LINK](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q1tz9dEmXWM&list=PLEAQNNR8IlB4S8nNUlS0ArfgU1nXlhdRu&index=12)

So set up the latest Eclipse and Tomcat.
I used JSF 2.2.8 to stay close to the tutorial.

In this tutorial there are two xhtml files generated:

hello-world.xhtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:a="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough">

    <h:head>
        <title>Hello World - Input Form</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:inputText id="name" value="#{theUserName}"
            a:placeholder="What's your name?"/>
            <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="myresponse"/>
    </h:body>

</html>
```

myresponse.xhtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">

    <h:head>
        <title>Hello World - Response</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        Hello, #{theUserName}
    </h:body>

</html>
```

Everything works finde and the hello-world page is displayed in the Eclipse Browser. But when I'm clicking on Submit nothing happens.

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Your issue matches #1 of abovelinked duplicate.

Comment: By the way, the tutorial which you linked there did it correctly ..

Comment: What do you mean with "the tutorial did is correctly". Is my code correct or did you check the tutorial?

Comment: https://youtu.be/Q1tz9dEmXWM?t=119

Comment: oh no. I have looked at this so often and didn't see that. Sorry. My mistake!! I forgot the FORM TAG